# Elliot Haughin Twitter Codeigniter API User access token and access secret issues

Tags: api, codeigniter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Haughin's Twitter Codeigniter API to Login with twitter. Now i need to be able to post tweets on User's behalf. The problem is, I first need to find and get the user's access token and user's secret and store them in my database for later use. Where do I find those once I made the connection to twitter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hi its an old library try this library [new twitter library](https://github.com/vixnet/codeigniter-twitter)

Comment: i have the new one. I just don't know how to retrieve the user access token and secret once they allowed my application to read/write

Comment: use codeigniter-oauth library by phil for login and saving info about user and use this library for tweet user status here oauth library https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2